# File.Exists return false despite file is present in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to load an image in imagebox through a url, if the specfic image exists then, that image will be show otherwise a dummy avatar will be shown. For this i am checking the file using this

```
File.Exists(imagePathComplete)
```

But the problem is it is always returning false. I check that it can have permission problem. So for the soulion i tried alternate solution which is

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(imagePathComplete);
```

But it giving me error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException occured in mscorlib.dll but was not
>   not handled in user code . . .

Comment: debug it and copy the value of `imagePathComplete` and paste it into windows explorer...i know it seems obvious but had to suggest as a starting point

Comment: Yes i have confirmed, it is exists

Comment: is it a full path or relative?

Comment: it is full path at specific IP address. Actually it is my own IP, i am testing my winForm app using my own ip

Comment: so is it something like this: `\\localhost\c$\my_dir\some_file.txt` ??

Comment: if it's not then there's your problem...ie you need the `unc` path format

Comment: No it is  http://192.9.210.122/esp/img/employee/315079.jpg

Comment: use `unc` format like i showed you

Answer (score 1):

use this [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) format:

```
\\192.9.210.122\d$\wamp\esp\img\employee\315079.jpg
```

Comment: It is in WAMP folder in D drive.